# MS Access 2007 Identifying uniqueness of records in Table/Forms based on a number of fields

Tags: sql, forms, events, ms-access, combobox

Hi I am using Microsoft Access v2007 and I am a begineer, so am having trouble with doing the following. 
I have one Table that contains three fields (plus additonal assciated fields) the combination of which uniquely defines a record. For example, Field 1: 'Chapter number', Field 2: 'Section number', Field 3: 'Section version'. So there are many chapters that will have the same 'Section number', which in turn will have several revised section versions. I would like to do the following: create a drop down list or combo box in Field 1 which selects which chapter the user wants, then in Field 2 it should automatically list only the 'section numbers' that are already present within in that Chapter (this has already been entered in a Table in Access). Similarly for Field 3, the drop down box in Field 3 then only shows options that are relevant to that particular 'Section number' for that particular 'chapter number'. An example is as follows: Lets say the user selected Chapter 1 for a record in Field 1. This chapter has 10 section numbers but he is interested in section number 2 only. So he uses the drop down box in Field 2 which should now only show him the 10 sections. Then Field 3 should have the drop down box showing the versions this section number has, which say has been revised 4 times therefore, having four version numbers in all. How to make Access do the above. The combo box seems to list all the records in all field 1, 2 and 3 irrespective of what record has been selected in Field 1 which should restrict the drop down list in Field 2 and so on. 
Thanks in advance for any advice and suggestions.

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: Have you tried anything?  It's a lot easier to provide an answer when given a starting point...  Unless your intention was for someone else to write it up from scratch